# reverse ssh tunnel and raspberry pi

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi, reverse, tunnel

I've read many posts about my problem. However, I'm still unable to have my ssh tunnel working. Here is an example:

I have Ubuntu machine at "house_A", ip_A, and a RaspberryPi at "house_B" with ip_B.

I type the following command in RaspberryPi command line:

```
~$ ssh -Ntg -R *:2222:127.0.0.1:22 user_A@ip_A
```

Then I type

```
~$ nestat -a |grep 2222
```

in my ubuntu and this is the output:

```
tcp        0      0 *:2222                  *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:2222               [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

And after this I type on Ubuntu (house_A, user_A, ip_A)

```
~$ ssh user_B@localhost -p 2222
```

(user_B=pi)
but it seems the call remain in a waiting status.

- I tried with all the tutorials I found:
- I tested it with other ports (10000, 10001+)
  on my router i have my pc in DMZ and i redirect to it the calls on port 22
- I even tried with 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.xxx and public IP instead of "localhost" and i added "GatewayPorts yes" in /etc/ssh/sshd_config
- I added a public key so host A and B can ssh-ing each other without explicit password

I have 4 RaspberryPi devices in different places, I cant use static public IPs for those rpi and i cant forward ports on each router.

Comment: pinging the remote hosts works?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I regret to say it, but the question is practically unreadable. Therefore, there is a chance that you won't get an answer. Check this help page first http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is the `*:` doing on the front of your -R switch parameter `*:2222:127.0.0.1:22`? I don't do much reverse tunneling, but shouldn't it just be `-R 2222:127.0.0.1:22` to set it up?

Comment: hi everybody and thanks to all.
i tried to be clear, sorry if i wasnt...
yes i can ping the remote host and i saw the " * " before the " :2222 " in a forum post when i was using -R 2222:127.0.0.1:22

i recieved a reply just 5 minutes ago and now it's working fine:

~$ ssh -N -R \*:2222:<public_ip_B>:22 <user_A>@<public_ip_A>

now i can communicate with the host_B typing: 

~$ ssh localhost -p 2222
ps
as  i can understand \* is used to say "all interfaces"...